# org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition() Example with Java 7

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have **org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset** and intend to iterate through each row. I see that there methods as **foreach** and **foreachPartition**, but i don't see documentation or examples using it. I am referring to the doc [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession)

Spark 2.1

Java 7

Cassandra 3.9

Can somebody guide me how to iterate through records of Spark Dataset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the way,

```
dataset.foreachPartition(new ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>() {
            public void call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception {
                while (t.hasNext()){

                    Row row = t.next();
                    System.out.println(row.getString(2));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Will the sout print inside a spark operation ? will it give the value of row.getString(2). ?

Answer (score -1):

```
def foreach(func: ForeachFunction[T]): Unit
 (Java-specific) Runs func on each ***element*** of this Dataset.

def foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit
 Applies a function f to all ***rows***.

def foreachPartition(func: ForeachPartitionFunction[T]): Unit
 (Java-specific) Runs func on each partition of this Dataset.

def foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit
 Applies a function f to each partition of this Dataset.
```